# How to switch between different java versions in Linux?

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal, linux-mint

I manually installed Java 8 and installed Java 11 via command line (open-jdk). I'm a noob at linux and don't know how to switch between the versions.

I ran the following commands to change the default version.

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

**Returns:**

```
  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1101      auto mode
  1            /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java               1         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1101      manual mode
```

And

```
update-alternatives --config javac
```

**Returns:**

```
There is only one alternative in link group javac (providing /usr/bin/javac): /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
Nothing to configure.
```

Comment: It seems that only the OpenJDK 11 installation has a JDK (i.e. all the build tools including `javac`), whereas the Java 8 install is a pure JRE. Make sure that the `-jdk` package for both are installed and you'll be able to tweak `javac` using `update-alternatives` just as you did with `java`.

Comment: How do I remove the one that I manually installed?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [SDKMan](https://sdkman.io/) which allow us to do the same, SDKMan is a free to use open-sourced tool which helps us to install and manage parallel versions of around 29 Software Development Kits such as Java, Groovy, Scala, Kotlin and Ceylon. Ant, Gradle, Grails, Maven, SBT, Spark, Spring Boot, Vert.x.

And it also sets the `_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables automatically.

You can install SDKMan by running below commands

```
$ curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
$ source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

You can list all versions of Java using

```
$ sdk list java
```

And you can install different-different Java versions using `sdk install` command
e.g.

```
$ sdk install java 9.0.4-open
$ sdk install java 11.0.2-open
```

And you can switch between them using `sdk use` and `sdk default` commands, You can read more about it on my blog [How to Install Multiple Versions of Java on the Same Machine](https://www.programmingmitra.com/2019/03/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-java-on-the-same-machine.html).

Comment: For anyone trying `java -version` or `echo $JAVA_HOME` and noticing that their version still hasn't changed after doing this, you may need to close and reopen your terminal to see the changes reflected.