# Switch between multiple R versions..?

Tags: r

I want to install 3 R version such as 4.1.2, 4.2.2, 4.3.2.  I want to install the R versions programmatically using subprocess in python language.  How can I install different R version and set as  default R version?

I found some solution for java language. Didn't find anything in R.

[How to switch between different java versions in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856882/how-to-switch-between-different-java-versions-in-linux)

Comment: Your intended setup is not clear. You need to describe it in more detail, in particular why and how python is involved. I deduce you are on a linux OS?

Comment: This is easy, just install the three the normal way you do, then to open a version you want, go to Rstudio and open it with CTRL + left_click, it should give you an option to select the version you want. Open three Rstudio windows with 3 different versions. And then you could toggle back and forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use Linux, you could use environments with Miniconda.

1. Install [Miniconda3](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html)
2. Search available R versions

```
conda search -c conda-forge r-base
```

3. Create environment named "R-4.1.2" and install that ancient R version

```
conda create -n R-4.1.2 -y -c conda-forge r-base=4.1.2
```

4. Activate that environment

```
conda activate R-4.1.2
```

5. Check R version of environment

```
(R-4.1.2) user@server:~$ R --version | head -n 1
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
```

while outside of the environments you still have your current version.

```
(R-4.1.2) user@server:~$ conda deactivate
(base) user@server:~$ conda deactivate
user@server:~$ R --version | head -n 1
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31) -- "Eye Holes"
```

For more information/uninstall see [conda.io](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html).